# default celery named Queues in RaabitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery and rabbitmq for a django project in which i have created two queues `queue_email` and `queue_push` running with one worker.

But rabbitmq has following queues as well, created by default:

```
celery
celery.pidbox
celeryev
reply.celery.pidbox
```

How and why these default queues are created ?

Can they be removed, if not necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some imformation in github. But incomplete.

1.The celeryev queues contain the messages celerymon and Flower use for monitoring purposes.

2.Pidbox is the broadcast messaging system used by celery to support remote control of workers.

Refference:
These issues may be help:
[Preventing Celery from creating Exchanges celery, celeryev, celeryev.pidbox, reply.celery.pidbox #3895](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3895)
[Hundreds of queues being created #1801](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1801)